# Count Query records to a text box in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to count the number of records in a query(named DUNKEL) to a text box. Here is what I did. In the Expression builder of the text box I have the following code :

```
=Format(Dcount("*","DUNKEL"),"000")
```

It gives me a syntax error. Where am I going wrong with it?

Comment: Try to replace comas by ";". This depends on your regional settings

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted, it will help other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments separator depends on operating system regional locale and may be coma or semicolon. If your current locale has separator “;”, just replace comas to semicolons.